# Provider org.apache.spark.sql.avro.AvroFileFormat could not be instantiated

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming-kafka, spark-avro

Unable to send avro format message to Kafka topic from spark streaming application. Very less information is available online about avro spark streaming example code. "to_avro" method doesn't require avro schema then how it will encode to avro format?

**Can someone please help to resolve below exception?**

Dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-avro_2.12</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Below is the code to push to kafka topic

```
dataset.toDF.select(to_avro(struct(dataset.toDF.columns.map(column):_*))).alias("value").distinct.write.format("avro")
      .option(KafkaConstants.BOOTSTRAP_SERVER, priBootStrapServers)
      .option(ApplicationConstants.TOPIC_KEY, publishPriTopic)
      .save()
```

Getting below exception.

````
Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceRegister: Provider org.apache.spark.sql.avro.AvroFileFormat could not be instantiated
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:232)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(ServiceLoader.java:185)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:384)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
    at scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$JIteratorWrapper.next(Wrappers.scala:43)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.filterImpl(TraversableLike.scala:247)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.filter(TraversableLike.scala:259)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.filter(Traversable.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:614)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:241)
    at com.walmart.replenishment.edf.dao.EdfOwBuzzerDao$.saveToCassandra(EdfOwBuzzerDao.scala:47)
    at com.walmart.replenishment.edf.process.BuzzerService$.updateScrItemPriStatus(BuzzerService.scala:119)
    at com.walmart.replenishment.edf.process.BuzzerStreamProcessor$$anonfun$processConsumerInputStream$1.apply(BuzzerStreamProcessor.scala:36)
    at com.walmart.replenishment.edf.process.BuzzerStreamProcessor$$anonfun$processConsumerInputStream$1.apply(BuzzerStreamProcessor.scala:28)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(DStream.scala:628)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(DStream.scala:628)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:416)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.Job.run(Job.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(JobScheduler.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:257)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler.run(JobScheduler.scala:256)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormat.$init$(Lorg/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/FileFormat;)V
    at org.apache.spark.sql.avro.AvroFileFormat.(AvroFileFormat.scala:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:380)
    ```
````

Comment: You are using `spark-avro` version `2.4.4` while spark version is `2.4.0`. Did you tried to use the same version?

Comment: @shuvalov Yes, tried with `spark-avro` version 2.4.0 as well, still issue is same.

Comment: Anyone can help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look at this [this ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-27623).  The problem seems to exist in 2.4.4 and 2.4.5.  I am still using version 2.4.4.  Switching to package `org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.11:2.4.4` fixed the issue for me.

Comment: I had the same issue, I am using Spark2.4.5, This solution works for me as well by switching package to org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.11:2.4.5

Comment: Thanks for confirming!

Comment: I confirm on a different package as well: I was using `com.google.cloud.spark:spark-bigquery-with-dependencies_2.12:0.18.1` in Spark 3 and when changed to Spark 2.4 I was receiving a similar error message. I downgraded to `com.google.cloud.spark:spark-bigquery-with-dependencies_2.11:0.18.1` and it worked for me!

Answer (score 4):

The scala version of *spark-avro_2.12* should be  Consistent with spark-core version.

You can use `spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.12:2.4.4 ...`, Or `spark-submit --jars "spark-avro_2.11-2.4.4.jar"`.

In a word, when you use databricks avro, you also should use apache avro jars.

reference to "https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-avro.html#deploying"

Answer (score 1):

I had to use `2.12:2.4.5` (`org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.12:2.4.5`) for my dataproc cluster with `1.5` [image (spark version: 2.4)](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/versioning/dataproc-release-1.5).

no other version (`2.11:2.4.5` / `2.11:2.4.4`) worked.